# Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName..... | Name or service not known

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-powershell, azure-keyvault

I have a pipeline in which i calling a power-shell script which copy the azure keyvault secrets from one key-vault to another keyvault.
Here's the powershell script:

```
    $SecretNames =   "api-gateway--jwt-public-key",
    "authentication-service--jwt-private-key",
    "user-management--pen-password",
    "user-management--stripe-secret-key"

    $sourceVaultName="fdevcuskv03"
    $destVaultName="fdevcuskv04"

    for (($i = 0); $i -lt $SecretNames.Count; $i++)
    {
        $sourceSecretName = "$($SecretNames[$i])"
        $destSecretName = "$($SecretNames[$i])"
        
        $Getvalue=(Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $sourceVaultName -Name $sourceSecretName).SecretValue
        Write-Host "Copying $sourceSecretName Value To $destSecretName"

        
        Set-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $destVaultName -Name $destSecretName `
            -SecretValue $Getvalue
    }
```

When I run the pipeline, I got this error but this works fine locally.
Here's the error:

```
    Get-AzKeyVaultSecret: /home/vsts/work/1/s/Terraform/Terraform-Scripts/main.ps1:351
    Line |
    351 |  …  $Getvalue=(Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $sourceVaultName -Name $s …
        |                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        | Name or service not known
```

I'm bit confused, what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Are you sure your script is connected to the right subscription (`Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $SubscriptionId`) and that the credentials it's running under have access to read from the source keyvault resource?

Comment: Sidenote: you could replace your `for (($i = 0); $i -lt $SecretNames.Count; $i++)` statement with `foreach ($secretName in $SecretNames)` and do away with `$sourceSecretName` and `$destSecretName` using instead `$secretName` as the source and dest names are always the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along with checking  that please check also if the case maybe dns resolution issue or invalid dns cache causing the error .

For that please try to give it sleep time and repeat the step.(Also check  by dns flush )
Place check [azure-powershell issues(github)](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/1524#issuecomment-534104725) comment by @placidseven  ang set azure keyvault by first checking if dns Is resolved.

```
foreach(($i = 0); $i -lt $SecretNames.Count; $i++)
    {
        $sourceSecretName = "$($SecretNames[$i])"
        $destSecretName = $sourceSecretName 
        
        $Getvalue=(Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $sourceVaultName -Name $sourceSecretName).SecretValue
        Write-Host "Copying $sourceSecretName Value To $destSecretName"
setSecret

function setSecret{
    while (!$secret) {
$DnsCheck = Resolve-DnsName $VaultURI -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

     if (!$DnsCheck) {
        write-host "Resolve-DnsName taking time to resolve $vaultName. Keep trying!"
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 30
Set-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $destVaultName -Name  $destSecretName `
            -SecretValue $Getvalue -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }
}

$secret = Set-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $destVaultName -Name  $destSecretName `
            -SecretValue $Getvalue -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
setSecret
}
}
```

**Reference**: [Set-AzureKeyVaultSecret does not recognize vaultName · GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/1524)